# How do you code a tumblr page where an intro picture links to the main post?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

An example is [this website](http://theoatmeal.com/), where a picture links to the actual post (like an archive page). How do I code this on tumblr?

Answer (score 0):

you could try doing this:

```
<a href="{Permalink}"><img src="you know what goes here"></a>
```

Make sure this is **between** your {block:Photo} **and** {/block:Photo} code though, otherwise it won't work.

If this doesn't make any sense whatsoever, I advise you to do some reading here:
[Basic Posts Markup Tumblr](http://buildthemes.tumblr.com/ch2/post-markup)

Good luck!